# retrieve More complex JSON via Ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to receive data from JSON via AJAX, but the JSON structure is more complex rather than just one value/key.

Here's the code I'm stuck:

```
$.ajax('data.json', {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, text, xhqr) {
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      console.log(data.Cars);
      $("body").html(data.Cars)
    });
 }
});
```

JSON:

```
{
   "extracted" : "2014-03-18 13:00:12",
   "LastRun" : "2014-03-18 13:00:00",
   "Cars" : {
      "Audi" : {
         "Total" : "18",
         "Type" : "Sport",
         "features" : {
            "Airbag" : "yes",
            "Radio" : "No",
            "Convertible" : "yes"
         }
      },
      "Ford" : {
         "Total" : "109",
         "Type" : "Sport",
         "features" : {
            "Airbag" : "yes",
            "Radio" : "No",
            "Convertible" : "no"
         }
      },
      "Mercedes" : {
         "Total" : "60",
         "Type" : "Luxury",
         "features" : {
            "Airbag" : "No",
            "Radio" : "Yes",
            "Convertible" : "yes"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the data to be displayed in this table format:
[image]

Can someone help me please how to receive or read the json values/keys?
Many thanks

Comment: That's a strange looking $.ajax call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
    var table = $('<table />'),
        thead = $('<thead />'),
        tbody = $('<tbody />');

    thead.append(
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<th />', {text: 'Car'}),
            $('<th />', {text: 'Type'}),
            $('<th />', {text: 'Airbag'}),
            $('<th />', {text: 'Radio'}),
            $('<th />', {text: 'Convertible'}),
            $('<th />', {text: 'Total'})
        )
    );

    $.each(data.Cars, function(car, specs) {
        tbody.append(
            $('<tr />').append(
                $('<td />', {text: car}),
                $('<td />', {text: specs.Type}),
                $('<td />', {text: specs.features.Airbag}),
                $('<td />', {text: specs.features.Radio}),
                $('<td />', {text: specs.features.Convertible}),
                $('<td />', {text: specs.Total})
            )
        );
    });

    $('body').append( table.append(thead, tbody) );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V75C8/)

Comment: that's amazing. Thank you very much!! Imagine there would be another type/key something like Trucks along side Cars. Would the call look like this? '$.each(data.Cars.Trucks, function(car, specs) {...});'

Comment: Uhm, something like that, it's hard to say exactly, but if you take the code above and try to follow the variables, insert a few console logs etc. it's not that hard to understand how the iteration and accessing the properties etc. work. Once you get how it works, you'll be able to do this kind of thing easily by just looking at the JSON and creating iterations and elements based on that.